# Errors with Inequality join in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, date-parsing, inequality

I am performing a self join in Hive and doing aggregations (percentile) on the window included in the join condition and I am getting the following errors -

```
Error1:
FAILED: SemanticException Line x: Both left and right aliases
encountered in JOIN ..."
```

```
Error2:
Invalid function 'DATE_PARSE'
```

The code looks like below-

```
SELECT
      a.id
    , a.date
    , a.groups
    , a.items
    , PERCENTILE_APPROX(b.quantity, 0.75) AS rolling_percent_75
  FROM (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT
      id
    , date
    , groups
    , items
    FROM
      table1) AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table1 AS b
  ON
        a.id         = b.id
    AND a.groups     = b.groups
    AND a.items      = b.items
    AND b.date      >= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_PARSE(a.date, 'yyyyMMdd'), -10, 'yyyyMMdd'))   
    AND b.date      <= a.date   
  GROUP BY
    1, 2, 3, 4
  ORDER BY
    1, 2, 3, 4
```

How to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(str,format))` to convert string to date(date_purse function) and `DATE_ADD` to minus date values.

You can use below section in your query and replace existing inequality.

```
 AND b.date      >= DATE_ADD(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(a.date, 'yyyyMMdd')), -10)   
    AND b.date      <= a.date   
``
```